# textNode.parentNode skips anchor tag in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to get the anchor tag from a selected context, by looping through the startContainer's parents, like so:

```
function getUrlFromSelection() {
  let $target = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer;

  while ($target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'body') {
    if ($target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
      return $target;
    }
    $target = $target.parentNode;
  }

  return null;
}
```

This is working fine, but Edge seems to skip the anchor tag.

Let's take a look at an example:

```
<div> 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed 
  diam nonumy <a href="#">eirmod</a> tempor invidunt ut labore 
  et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
</div>
```

If I select the `<a href="#">eirmod</a>` and invoke `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer` I get a reference to the textNode. If I call `textNode.parentNode` I get the reference to the surrounding div and not to the anchor tag. This behavior only occurs in Edge.